# How to achieve `<apex:input type="range" />`

Tags: visualforce, html5, api-29

I'm trying to use HTML5 and the Winter'14 support for it [(code sample if you haven't seen it yet)](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_vforce_html5_code_sample.htm).

It works fine for `type="auto"`, but not for `type="range"`.
I'm trying to bind to an Integer and I'm getting this error:

```
Expected input type 'number', got 'range' for Decimal data type
```

Any ideas?

Here's simple piece of code to reproduce it (make sure the VF page is saved at least in v.28).

```
public class html5 {
    public Integer anInt {get;set;}
    public String aString {get;set;}

    public html5(){
        anInt = 0;
        aString = '0';
    }
}
<apex:page controller="html5" doctype="html-5.0" readonly="true" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:input label="this works" value="{!anInt}" type="auto" html-min="0" html-max="30" html-step="1" />
            <apex:input label="this throws" value="{!anInt}" type="range" html-min="0" html-max="30" html-step="1" />
            <apex:input label="this throws too" value="{!aString}" type="range" html-min="0" html-max="30" html-step="1" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I've tried faking it by overriding the type in the pass-through (`html-type="range"`), no luck. I know I can always use JS to create the slider or use hacks from other questions (like raw html5 input + JS sync to the hidden one on submit)... But would be nice to have.

Seems like HTML5 support is half-baked yet.

Comment: Did you try to use Decimal instead of Integer?

Comment: What browser?  I read that IE has issues with the HTML range element.

Comment: @JimRae any, it's a compilation error. Still, good to know, that might mean I shouldn't spend too much time trying to get it to work ;)

Comment: @brovasi same error

Comment: Maybe it should be logged with support.  I found an article about implementing it and the author had the same problem.

Comment: range element works fine in IE if you declare an html5 doctype

Comment: @PhilR - as I mentioned in comments above - it used to be a compilation error. And I believe I've set the doctype all right in the examples. If you have access to Winter'14 org you can still "try" it yourself :)

Comment: sorry, youre right, I didn't read this carefully enough and was talking about `<input type="range">` instead of `<apex:input type="range">`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

It indeed works in Spring'14. Doesn't look very exciting if used standalone but then the slider was [designed with imprecise control in mind](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.range.html) so I guess I shouldn't complain ;)

Here's how it looks with a client-side output hooked to it:

[image]

```
<apex:page controller="html5" doctype="html-5.0"
    showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" id="page">
    <apex:form id="form"
        html-oninput="out.value = document.getElementById('page:form:range').value">
        <apex:input id="range" value="{!anInt}" type="range" 
            html-min="0" html-max="30" html-step="1" />
        <output name="out">0</output>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

**Original:**

Just got a call & case closed comment from SF Dev Support representative.

*Case #09986593*

> (..) please allow me to confirm that our Research & Development team is
>   working on the issue and indeed is scheduled to be fixed in the
>   upcoming Spring '14 release, which you can test in any sandbox
>   upgrades during January.

So not long to wait now (sandboxes refreshed [before Jan 3rd](http://blogs.salesforce.com/company/2013/11/spring-14-sandbox-preview-instructions.html) should get it)...

Comment: Spring 14 release still doesn't support range type. Here is a jQuery solution: http://www.tehnrd.com/add-slider-to-a-visualforce-page-with-jquery/

Comment: @PerlDev It worked for me! Are you sure you've picked API version 29?

Comment: I picked version 30.